# Why use dummy slots?

Tags: python, dictionary, cpython

In Cpython implementation,when we delete a key in a dict,Cpython will set the correspond entry to a dummy entry,why a dummy entry? Can i just let the ertry's value to be nil?

I'm not good at C,so i mock it in python,follow is my python's implement code:

```
class DictEntry:
def __init__(self):
    self.key = None
    self.value = None
    self.hash = None
def __repr__(self):
    return ' %s %s %s' % (self.key, self.hash, self.value)


class Hashtable:
def __init__(self):
    self.size = 8
    self.used = 0
    self.mask = self.size - 1
    self.pow2 = 3
    self.entyies = [DictEntry() for _ in range(self.size)]

def insert(self, key, item):
    hash_value = _hash(key)
    _key = hash_value & (self.size - 1)
    if not self.is_slot_empty(_key):
        _key = self.next_slot(_key, hash_value)
    entry = self.entyies[_key]
    entry.key = _key
    entry.hash = hash_value
    entry.value = item
    self.used += 1
    # if need resize
    if self.size * 2 / 3 < self.used:
        old_entyies = self.entyies
        self.entyies = [DictEntry() for _ in range(self.size * 2)]
        self.size = 2 * self.size
        self.mask = self.size - 1
        self.pow2 += 1
        for entry in old_entyies:
            if entry.value:
                self.insert(entry.key, entry.value)

def delete(self, obj):
    # delete won't resize
    # find the slot
    hash_value = _hash(obj)
    key = hash_value & (self.size - 1)
    perturb = hash_value
    PERTURB_SHIFT = 5
    while self.entyies[key].hash != hash_value:
        print(self.entyies[key].value, obj)
        key = key * 5 + 1 + perturb
        perturb <<= PERTURB_SHIFT
        key = key % 2 ** self.pow2

    # set to empty
    entry = self.entyies[key]
    entry.key = None
    entry.hash = None
    entry.value = None
    self.used -= 1

def getitem(self, obj):
    hash_value = _hash(obj)
    key = hash_value & (self.size - 1)
    perturb = hash_value
    PERTURB_SHIFT = 5
    while self.entyies[key].hash != hash_value:
        key = key * 5 + 1 + perturb
        perturb <<= PERTURB_SHIFT
        key = key % 2 ** self.pow2
    return self.entyies[key].value

def next_slot(self, key, hash_value):
    # open_address
    perturb = hash_value
    PERTURB_SHIFT = 5
    while not self.is_slot_empty(key):
        key = key * 5 + 1 + perturb
        perturb <<= PERTURB_SHIFT
        key = key % 2 ** self.pow2
    return key

def is_slot_empty(self, key):
    if self.entyies[key].value:
        return False
    return True

def __repr__(self):
    return '%s' % [(entry.hash, entry.value) for entry in self.entyies]enter code here
```

And i can insert,delete value as i wish.
when i want a empty entry, i will test if the entry's value is None.So I do not clear the design of 'dummy entry' for?

Can anyone show me the 'dummy' feature and point out the mistake in my code?

Comment: but in Cpython implementation,dummy slot is not equal to empty slot,there must some purpose.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: The mock implementation doesn't do a good job of reflecting the C; in the real implementation, there's a distinction between regular empty cells and deleted entry markers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(Note: I'm not that familiar with the internals of Python's `dict` implementation, I'm speaking of hashtables in general here.)

The basic idea of a hashtable is that you can derive a hash value from the key, and use it to go directly to the table entry that holds the corresponding value.  However, any implementation has to deal with the possibility that two different keys have the same hash value (or otherwise get mapped to the same entry index by the modulo operation performed on the hash value).  Python handles this via a strategy called "closed hashing": if the proper entry is already taken by a different key, a calculated sequence of other possible entries are checked, until an empty one is finally found.  (The table is not allowed to get anywhere near 100% full, so that this check never takes an unreasonable amount of time, and is guaranteed to find an empty entry.)  The implementation of `get()` follows the same sequence, until either the right key is found, or an empty entry is found.

Now, imagine that two keys `A` and `B`, that have a hash collision, are inserted into the dict in that order, and then `A` is deleted. If you implemented that by setting `A`'s entry to empty, then consider what would happen on a subsequent call to `get(B)`: it would immediately find that empty entry, and report that `B` is not present at all!  This problem can be fixed by having a special flag value, distinct from either an actual key or an empty entry, that is used to indicate a deleted entry.  When `get()` sees one of these, it knows it needs to keep looking in other possible entry locations.  When `set()` sees one, it can overwrite it with the key being inserted (although it will still need to scan until it finds an actual empty entry, to make sure the key is not already present).

Comment: Thx,I understand! It preserve the probe order!